# Get Current Track Information in SoundCloud Custom Player

Tags: soundcloud

I am almost done creating my sound cloud streaming custom player, but I would like the option to add the title and artist of the song that is currently playing.

Right now I have this: http://hellkeepers.com/music/examples/sc-player-minimal.html

But I cannot seem to figure out where to find the current track information.

Comment: If you request a track using the API it should be in the json response. The same response you are using to get the stream url.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use that since I am not using the developer API? It is the custom player.

Comment: Sure you can. You have all the info you need [right here](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-custom-player/blob/master/js/sc-player.js#L132). It's all in the track variable.

Answer (score 0):

to get an image and the title you can use this code:

```
//get element by id from your iframe
var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
widget.getCurrentSound(function(music){
    artwork_url = music.artwork_url.replace('-large', '-t200x200');
    $('#song1').css('background', 'url(\"'+artwork_url+'\") ');
    //write the title in a div with the id "title"
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = music.title;
});
```

normaly you get a link with "-large" at the end and the size is 100x100. If you want other sizes you have to change the end with ".replace" like I did. A list with available sizes can you find here:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks (my size 200x200 is not listed but works. Maybe there are more sizes like every hundred px.)

with:

```
widget.getDuration(function(duration) {
    alert(duration);
}
```

you have the length of the song in milliseconds

with:

```
widget.getPosition(function(position) {
    alert(position);
}
```

you have the actual poisition of the song in milliseconds. you have to run a loop to get every second the actual time. And probably you have to calculate milliseconds into seconds and minutes.

Late but better then never my answer :D